# How mix in routes in Sinatra for a better structure

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I found nothing about how I can mix-in routes from another module, like this:

```
module otherRoutes
  get "/route1" do

  end
end    

class Server < Sinatra::Base
  include otherRoutes

  get "/" do
    #do something
  end
end
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You don't do *include* with Sinatra. You use extensions together with *register*.

I.e. build your module in a separate file:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

module Sinatra
  module OtherRoutes
    def self.registered(app)
      app.get "/route1" do
        ...
      end
    end
  end
  register OtherRoutes # for non modular apps, just include this file and it will register
end
```

And then register:

```
class Server < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::OtherRoutes
  ...
end
```

It's not really clear from the docs that this is the way to go for non-basic Sinatra apps. Hope it helps others.

Comment: Good one. I used your example here: https://github.com/bridgeutopia/simple-sinatra-mvc

Comment: Why do you need to register twice?

Comment: You need to call register from modular apps only, because the register in the route file will add only to the main namespace.

Answer (score 7):

You could do this:

```
module OtherRoutes
  def self.included( app )
    app.get "/route1" do
      ...
    end
  end
end

class Server < Sinatra::Base
  include OtherRoutes
  ...
end
```

Unlike Ramaze, Sinatra's routes are not methods, and so cannot use Ruby's method lookup chaining directly. Note that with this you can't later monkey-patch OtherRoutes and have the changes reflected in Server; this is just a one-time convenience for defining the routes.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer the use of sinatra-contrib gem to extend sinatra for cleaner syntax and shared namespace

```
  # Gemfile
  gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.4.7'
  gem 'sinatra-contrib', '~> 1.4.6', require: 'sinatra/extension'

  # other_routes.rb
  module Foo
    module OtherRoutes
      extend Sinatra::Extension
      get '/some-other-route' do
        'some other route'
      end
    end
  end

  # app.rb
  module Foo
    class BaseRoutes < Sinatra::Base
      get '/' do
        'base route'
      end

      register OtherRoutes
    end
  end
```

[sinata-contrib](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/) is maintained alongside the sinatra project

Answer (score 6):

Well you can also use the map method to map routes to your sinatra apps

```
map "/" do
  run Rack::Directory.new("./public")
end

map '/posts' do
  run PostsApp.new
end

map '/comments' do
  run CommentsApp.new
end


map '/users' do
  run UserssApp.new
end
```

Comment: A note of warning: the limitation of this approach is that map only accepts raw strings (no regexp allowed).

Comment: This seems to be a great way to organise the app, but is the limitation of having on strings still there?

Answer (score 3):

Just my two cents:

my_app.rb:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  set :root, File.expand_path('../', __FILE__)
  set :app_file, __FILE__
  disable :run

  files_to_require = [
    "#{root}/app/helpers/**/*.{rb}",
    "#{root}/app/routes/**/*.{rb}"
  ]

  files_to_require.each {|path| Dir.glob(path, &method(:require))}
  helpers App::Helpers
end
```

app/routes/health.rb:

```
MyApp.configure do |c|
  c.before do
    content_type "application/json"
  end

  c.get "/health" do
    { Ruby: "#{RUBY_VERSION}",
      Rack: "#{Rack::VERSION}",
      Sinatra: "#{Sinatra::VERSION}"
    }.to_json
  end
end
```

app/helpers/application.rb:

```
module App
  module Helpers
    def t(*args)
      ::I18n::t(*args)
    end

    def h(text)
      Rack::Utils.escape_html(text)
    end
  end
end
```

config.ru:

```
require './my_app.rb'
```