# How do I config.ru properly in modular Sinatra application.?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I'm trying to use subclassing style in Sinatra application. So, I have a main app like this.

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' 
  end

  ...
end

class AnotherRoute < MyApp
  get '/another'
  end

  post '/another'
  end
end
```

```
run Rack::URLMap.new \ 
  "/"       => MyApp.new,
  "/another" => AnotherRoute.new
```

In config.ru I understand that it's only for "GET" how about other resources (e.g. "PUT", "POST")? I'm not sure if I'm missing someting obvious. And also if I have ten path (/path1, /path2, ...) do I have to config them all in config.ru even though they are in the same class?

Comment: Why do you want to have different class per path? Why can't you have all URL mapping in MyApp?

Comment: I just want to make it easier to separate because my app is getting bigger and I don't want to scroll up and down all the time.

Comment: Did you take a look at [padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/)? It's quite a **flexible** wrapper on top of Sinatra.

Comment: Will check that out! thanks a lot. Can I deploy that on heroku?

Comment: I haven't tried it out. I can try this out in my free time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`URLMap`](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/URLMap.html) you specify a base url where the app should be mounted. The path specified in the map is not used when determining which route to use within the app itself. In other words the app acts as if it's root is *after* the path used in `URLMap`.

For example, your code will respond to the following paths:

- `/`: will be routed to the `/` route in `MyApp`
- `/another`: will go to the `/` route in `AnotherRoute`. Since `AnotherRoute` extends `MyApp` this will be the same as `/` in `MyApp` (but in a different instance).

  `URLMap` sees `/another` and uses it to map to `AnotherRoute`, stripping this part of the request from the path. `AnotherRoute` then only sees `/`.
- `/another/another`: will be routed to the two `/another` routes in `AnotherRoute`. Again, the first `another` is used by the URLMap to route the request to `AnotherRoute`. `AnotherRoute` then only sees the second `another` as the path.

  Note that this path will respond to both `GET` and `POST` requests, each being handled by the appropriate block.

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but I think you can achieve what you want by running an instance of `AnotherRoute`, with a `config.ru` that is just:

```
run AnotherRoute.new
```

Since `AnotherRoute` extends `MyApp`, the `/` route will be defined for it.

If you're looking for a way to add routes to an existing Sinatra application, you could [create a module with an `included` method that adds the routes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4685431/214790), rather than use inheritance.

Answer (score 15):

app.rb

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' 
  end
end
```

app2.rb If you want two separate files. Note this inherits from Sinatra::Base not MyApp.

```
class AnotherRoute < Sinatra::Base
  get '/'
  end

  post '/'
  end
end
```

The config.ru

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:default)

require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/lib/app.rb"
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/lib/app2.rb"


map "/" do
    run MyApp
end

map "/another" do
    run AnotherRoute
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You could write this as

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' 
  end
  get '/another'
  end

  post '/another'
  end
end
```

in config.ru

```
require './my_app'
run MyApp
```

Run:

```
rackup -p 1234
```

Refer to documentation at http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Serving%20a%20Modular%20Application