# Sinatra: Using routes from other files

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra, rack

I'm currently building a Ruby app using Rack and Sinatra but I'm failing in using routes, implemented in other than the main app file. My first try was like this:

In the main file:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'lib/web'

module NoCI
  class Main < Sinatra::Base
    include NoCI::Web
    load 'lib/web.rb'
  end
end
```

and in lib/web.rb:
    require 'sinatra'

```
module NoCI
  module Web
    get '/' do
      "Hello World"
    end
  end
end
```

But it did not work. Then I read about putting the routes into a sub class of my main class. No success either. Any hints, what I'm missing?

**Update:** I tried with 'require', 'include' and 'load', mixing all possible combinations, nothing worked for me.

Comment: I see the given answer as a (however good) workaround. I believe the true answer is found as answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681199/how-mix-in-routes-in-sinatra-for-a-better-structure . Why i will flag this question as duplicate now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `included` hook to implement what you want.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'lib/web'

module NoCI
  class Main < Sinatra::Base
    include NoCI::Web
  end
end
```

lib/web.rb

```
module NoCI
  module Web
    def self.included(base)
      base.get '/' do
        'Hello World!'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The code inside `included` will execute when you include this module, with the `NoCI::Base` as `base`.